# How to find date for a specific modification in Clearcase?

Tags: clearcase

I'm looking at a file that is checked out in my current view but refers to an old version in the development branch. This file was modified several times by several people in this same view without any checkins. I'm interested in a specific modification and I'd like to find out exactly when that modification was done and, ideally, by whom. Is that possible?

Comment: Is it a shared dynamic view with an hijacked file? Or a shared snapshot view, with an eclipsed file? Or is the file checked out?

Comment: The view is dynamic and the file of interest is currently checked out.

Comment: Then there is no history associated with local modifications done on a checked out file (in snap or dynamic view). I will post an answer later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the *same* view (snapshot or dynamic, UCM or not) is shared/accessed by several developer, then no: a checked out file would not benefit from any history.
Any modification would simply override the previous one without leaving any new version allowing to identify the user who just modified said file.

You can search by date or author only if those modifications are done and then checked-in.

Comment: So I suppose a good practice with Clearcase would be to create as many sub-branches as necessary and to checkin on those branches as often as possible.

Comment: @JohnND Yes, if you want history on a common file.